# Processing csv files with a queue using Kafka to insert to postgres database and return status message

Tags: postgresql, go, apache-kafka, queue, confluent-kafka-go

I looking for some best practices/advice to handle processing CSV file for inserting into the database with a queue mechanism (Kafka)

So here what i will do :

Create a new SQL table `Service Request` to store information of the user request like :

```
RequestID, Status, Payload, Response
```

as you can see i have field `status` to indicate the request is **succeed** or **failed**

So here is the flow when user upload CSV File :

1. Users submit a CSV file
2. Validate the CSV File to make sure it used the correct template
3. Upload CSV File to Google Cloud Storage and then create a new record on the table `Service Request` with RequestID and the Payload is URL of CSV File
4. Read all records on CSV File and send Queue to Kafka topic (with JSON payload)

On the consumer side :

1. Listen all incoming Queue of the topic (Consume the Queue)
2. Processing all the Queue
3. If there is an error create a CSV file to store why this Queue Failed
4. If all Queue of the RequestID XXX is finished then updated the `status` and set the response with a CSV file error list

> **So here is the question** :
> How do I know all Queue of the RequestID
> XXX is all consumed and I can update the `status`?

I am using :
Go + confluent-kafka-go **library**

**Updates**

After doing some research, I discovered that it should used Kafka Stream by implementing `GroupByKey`, is that possible to do that in Go ? i cant find the kafka stream api from **confluent-kafka-go**

Comment: I haven't worked with golang and kafka on the consumer side, but https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go had a nice producer API, might be worth checking out.

Comment: How big is that CSV file? Should not be faster just read the csv in streaming and insert batches into postgres?

Answer (score 1):

I am a Kafka novice, so I may not be the best person to be giving out advice, but my initial reaction would be to force message processing to occur "in order". On the producer side, you'd indicate the last message. On the consumer side, you'd read the indicator and once you reach the last message, you'd update the `Status` field. Keep in mind that forcing message order may have implications on system throughput.

Useful reading is available at https://medium.com/latentview-data-services/how-to-use-apache-kafka-to-guarantee-message-ordering-ac2d00da6c22

Another approach would be to use Postgres as a distributed lock and track progress there. For example, let's say you have a tracking table with the columns: `RequestId`, `RecordsProcessed`, `RecordsGenerated`. You'd lock the row or table and increment the `RecordsProcessed` column each time you consumed a message. Once you've processed all the records, you'd update the `Status` accordingly.